# How do I use jupyter notebook without token authentication?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm very new to Data Science and using anaconda/jupyter so please bear with me.

My instructor asked me to install anaconda, and to run the jupyter notebook to make sure everything was installed correctly. When I tried to do so, I am met with a prompt telling me that token authentication is enabled. My instructor said this is not supposed to happen, and I should've been able to move on directly to a page with a cell where I could run code. He couldn't help me.

I think the problem might be due to the fact that I am somehow running Anaconda Cloud when I shouldn't be. Any idea on how I can fix this problem?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot or something like this?

Comment: Newer versions of jupyter are token protected... Have you tried searching the jupyter documentation about disabling it?

Comment: https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/security.html#security-in-the-jupyter-notebook-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Token authentication is good for security purposes. I believe you would want it to just open directly locally. Switching the default browser from Safari to Chrome did it for me, another thing is you can set your own password in jupyter notebook in terminal.

`jupyter notebook password`